# Plotly: add space between value and units (honor SI)

Tags: plotly.js

According to [The International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units):

> The value of a quantity is written as a number followed by a space (representing a multiplication sign) and a unit symbol; e.g., 21 kg, 22 K.

I am trying to create a plot honoring that space, but it seems I am unable to. Plotly will add no space between the quantity and the unit symbol (MN in this case, after adding the mega prefix):

```js
const data = [
  {
    x: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    y: [20000000, 14000000, 23000000],
    type: 'bar',
  }
];

const layout = {
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Force',
    ticksuffix: 'N',
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('plotDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.6.3.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='plotDiv'></div>
</body>
```

How can I add that space between the quantity and the unit symbol?

Ideally:

- It should work well with any prefix (including no prefix)
- The space should be represented both in the y-axis and in the hover label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add `&nbsp;` to ticksuffix and `hoverformat:".1f"` and the result might be what you want. Note: `&nbsp;` is the escape code for a space.
I use hoverformat to avoid the default formatting (i.e. 12000000 becomes 12M on the hover text). It opens possibilities to manipulate the hovertext further if needed.

*EDIT*

I edited the code and the result obtained is better conform to what the OP request.

```js
const data = [
  {
    x: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    y: [20000000, 14000000, 12300000],
    type: 'bar',
  }
];

const average = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length;
const divby1e6 = (arr) => arr.map((a) => a / 1000000);
let meany = average(data[0].y);
let suffix = "N";
if (meany > 1e6) {
    // compute new y, prep suffix
    suffix = " M" + suffix;
    data[0].y = divby1e6(data[0].y);
  } 
else {
    // just in case
  }
const layout = {
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Force',
    hoverformat: ".3f",  //specify decimal digits
    ticksuffix: suffix,
    tickformat: '.3f'
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('plotDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.6.3.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='plotDiv'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Note how that results in `20M N` in the tick (with the space between the prefix and the unit, instead of between the quantity and the prefix). The expected result should be `20 MN`.

Comment: @Peque On the contrary, I consider 20M a number (Plotly's standard) and N is a separate unit.

Comment: That does not comply with the [International System of Units (SI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units), which I want to honor as stated in my question. ;-)

Comment: You can have a look at the "General rules" section. In particular: *A prefix is part of the unit, and its symbol is prepended to a unit symbol without a separator*.

Comment: @Peque I have edited the code. Please check and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more convoluted. I tried looking in through the plotly API, but couldn't find a solution. However, the following code just generates its own tooltip.

Note the added css to the head tag as well.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.6.3.min.js'></script>

  <!-- Add the css to hide the plotly tooltip and create our own -->
  <style>
        /* hide plotly tooltip - we'll still use it for position and data */
        .main-svg g.hoverlayer g.hovertext {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        /* Style our own tooltip - you can play with the values as you wish */
        #tooltip {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            min-width: 80px; 
            height: 20px;
            background: #006eb6;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10;
            top: 0;
            margin-left: 10px;
            font-size: 10px;
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid white;
            border-left: 0 solid white;
        }

        /* create the triangle */
        #tooltip:before {
            content: "";
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            left: -10px;
            top: 0;
            position: absolute;
            border-top: 10px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
            border-right: 10px solid #006eb6;
        }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div id='plotDiv'></div>
</body>

<script>
  const data = [
  {
    x: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    y: [20000000, 14000000, 23000000],
    type: 'bar',
  }
];

const layout = {
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Force',
    ticksuffix: 'N'
    //ticksuffix: ' N'
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('plotDiv', data, layout);

// add the spacing to the axes
const yaxes = document.querySelectorAll('.ytick text')
for(let yaxis of yaxes) {
  yaxis.innerHTML = yaxis.innerHTML.replace(/(\d+)/g, (_, num) => num + ' ') 
}

// tooltip starts here
// create a new tool tip - add it to body and hide it on display
const tooltip = document.createElement('div')
tooltip.setAttribute('id', 'tooltip')
tooltip.style.display = "none"
document.body.appendChild(tooltip)


// add mousemove event to body to override plotly hover
// get the bounding box of each bar in the chart
const underbars = document.getElementsByClassName('point')
const positions = []
for(let underbar of underbars) {
    positions.push(underbar.getBoundingClientRect())
}

// add event to display tooltip when mouse cursor is inside bar
document.body.onmousemove = evt => {
    const x = evt.clientX 
    const y = evt.clientY 
   
    // check if cursor falls inside bar
    let position = null;
    positions.forEach(pi => {
        pi.left = pi.left + window.scrollX 
        pi.top = pi.top + window.scrollY
        if(x >= pi.left && x <= pi.left + pi.width && y >= pi.top && y <= pi.top + pi.height) {
            position = pi
        }
    })

    // if it does, get the data from plotly tool tip and add it to our own
    if(position) {
        // get position of tooltip
        const hover_element = document.querySelector('.main-svg g.hoverlayer g.hovertext')
        if(!hover_element) {
            return
        }
        const transform = hover_element.getAttribute('transform').replaceAll(' ', '')
        
        
        // get the text from plotly tooltip and set it to our tooltip adding a space
        const text = document.querySelector('.main-svg g.hoverlayer g.hovertext text').innerHTML

        tooltip.innerHTML = text.replace(/(\d+)/g, (_, num) => num + ' ') 

        // get position of our plotly tooltip - add px so its compatible with css
        tooltip.style.transform = transform.replace(/(\d+\.\d+)/g, (_, num) => num + 'px')

        // have to add scroll and position container offset - this allows the chart to 
        // be rendered anywhere on screen. Can +/- px's for finer control of tooltip 
        const cp = document.querySelector('.main-svg').getBoundingClientRect()
        tooltip.style.marginTop = window.scrollY + cp.top
        tooltip.style.marginLeft = window.scrollX + cp.left

        // display tooltip
        tooltip.style.display = 'flex'
    }
    else {

        // hide tooltip on exit
        tooltip.style.display = "none"
    }
}

</script>
<\html>
```

Perhaps someone more familiar with Plotly will chime in. Otherwise, let me know if I can add any clarifications.

Comment: Thanks! That works great for the tick labels. Is there a way to make it work with the hover label too? (hover the mouse over one bar to see the space missing).

Comment: No problem! Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind updating your answer to use a JavaScript snippet (similar to the one in the question or in swatchai's answer). This would allow anybody to execute and see the result of your solution with just one click. ^^

Comment: I don see a code snippet in either of your answers but im on my phone so maybe thats why, if you mean the syntax highlighting im not sure why it didnt highlight. Its silly to add so much code just for a space. Might as well just use d3. Or just divide your numbers by a million and use the ‘ MN’ prefix.

Comment: Maybe its mobile, yeah. Agreed with your statement, considering the complexity of the workaround. ^^